# When should I use "How many" rather than "How much"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

When should I use **"How many"** rather than **"How much"**?

Please, could give me some examples and or even gramatical rules about that.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between "many" and "much"? "How" doesn't really make a difference as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use "*How much"* to ask about mass nouns or uncountable nouns.
****For example:****

- How much **flour** and sugar does the recipe call for?

While we use *"How many"* to ask about countable nouns. Like measured, kinds,etc.
**For example:**

- How many ****cups of flour**** I need add to the recipie?